# Check input while typing (number only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check input's value while typing but my code seem not working (work on snippet but MVC VS 2013)
Something wrong with my code ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#txtAge').keyup(function(){
            var pattern = /^\d+$/;
            if(pattern.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val()!='' ){

                $("#age_error_message").hide();
                $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #34F458');
            }
            else if ($(this).val() =='') {
                $("#age_error_message").html("Please enter your age");
                $("#age_error_message").show();
                $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #F90A0A');
                
            }
            else {
                $("#age_error_message").html("Should contain number only");
                $("#age_error_message").show();
                $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #F90A0A');
                
            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
Age: <input name="age" id="txtAge" type="text" class="btn-sm form-control " placeholder="Your age" />
<span class="error-form btn-sm text-danger" id="age_error_message"></span>
```

Comment: your code working fine here.what's the issue?

Comment: Is there an error in your console?

Answer (score 2):

change like this .your code working fine

```
$('#txtAge').keyup(function(){
        var pattern = /^\d+$/;
        if(pattern.test($(this).val()) && $(this).val()!='' ){

            $("#age_error_message").hide();
            $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #34F458');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() =='') {
            $("#age_error_message").html("Please enter your age");
            $("#age_error_message").show();
            $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #F90A0A');

        }
        else {
            $("#age_error_message").html("Should contain number only");
            $("#age_error_message").show();
            $("#txtAge").css('border-bottom', '2px solid #F90A0A');

        }

    });
```

verified ..
https://jsfiddle.net/knv8grt6/

Comment: I din't see any change in code. you have the exact copy of OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

It seem my code doesnt work bcz i put multi functions in 'script' tag . When i create new 'script' tag then put my code in, it work fine. Can someone explain ?